# Running SSMS and SQL Server 2019 on Mac in a VM but .bak file is not showing up as a restore device How do I get it to show up?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am running SSMS in a VM on a Mac and downloaded a `.bak` file for AdventureWorks. For some reason when I try to restore the database using the device option I am not seeing the file or any of my local drives on the VM. I am also not seeing a backup folder that I am seeing on many Youtube videos on this topic. How do I solve this?

I have tried saving the file to multiple different locations and none of the seem to be what SSMS/SQL Server wants in order to restore. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: I hope, you are connected to some SQL Server

Comment: I am connected to a local SQL Server that is running in a Docker Container

Comment: The `.bak` file needs to be **local** in relation to where the SQL Server process runs. If it's on a remote server - the `.bak` file needs to be on that server. In a Docker container, I assume you have a local file system - the `.bak` file needs to be on that Docker file system somewhere - *not* local on your Mac host machine ...

Comment: I was able to solve this after I knew to move the file into the Docker container! Thank you!